# Android: add labels to clickable views

Tags: java, android, label

Is there any common way to add a label to any clickable View to show what it does? For example if I long press a gear button I want the user see a label "Options". Something like this in WhatsApp

[image: Label for button]

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your corresponding view

```
android:tooltipText="Sample Text"
```